# Under what circumstances can an extern variable be used in definition?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-management, extern

I am very very sorry. I didn't know my incomplete code attachment would create such a mess. I am very glad to see so many sincere helps.

This code will compile:

```
int myadd(int, int);
static int main_stat = 5;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    main_stat = 13;
    j = myadd(-1,7);
    i = main_stat;

    cout << j << i;     //  3  and 13
    return 0;

}
```

myadd.cpp

```
extern int main_stat = -3;
int myadd(int x,int y)
{
    int t = main_stat;
    t = x + y;
    y = t +main_stat;
    return y;    // will return 3
}
```

See I defined and extern linking main_stat. Why is that legal? I thought you could only link and not define.

Is storage allocated in the stack frame of myadd function call? Global static are allocated on heap, I believe, right?

---

### EDIT

I am sorry, but I think this time I will narrow down my questions:

From C++ Primer 4ed

> An **extern** declaration may include an initializer (when combined
>   becomes definition) only if it appears outside a function.

I am clear about one-definition rule.

Q1. Which copy of main_stat does myadd(int,int) uses when it is called? The same copy as the main has, but with a different value (which I can test) ? Or does each function has its own static global copy?

Q2. Is memory allocated on the heap for these global static variables? I know many things are up to implementation, but isn't heap used for static variables?

Q3. I know the followings two are valid

```
extern int x;    // means int x is defined elsewhere
extern int x = 3;  // declared and defined
```

Why do we want the second one if we can just declare a static global variable within the namespace of myadd ? How does it ***make things clear*** like aschepler said?

Comment: @Mehrdad, hmm, excuses me? I don't get it :x

Comment: @mehrdad, I see what you there.

Comment: @CppLearner: You accidentally part of the question title

Comment: Not sure what the confusion is.  Please show a simple example of "main function in another file".

Comment: @aschepler: He's noted that, typically, `extern` is used on variables to signify that the definition & storage are found in a different TU. He's thus wondering about the semantics of `extern` on a variable when the definition & storage are in fact right there in the same decl/defn.

Comment: @aschepler I just added. Thanks to all.

Comment: You have two different variables named `main_stat`.  The one in the main file marked `static` has "internal linkage", meaning it is not the same as any variable from any other file.  The program would act the same if you deleted the unnecessary variable definition from the main file.

Comment: @aschepler Yes. I just finalized my post. Sorry for all the mess. So are you saying that since they are all global variables, they are two different entities?

Answer (score 9):

All variable declarations with an initializer are also definitions;
that's an overriding rule.  Regardless of `extern`.  There are even
cases where you need an `extern` on a definition: you can only
instantiate a template using a variable which has external linkage.  And 
`const` variables have internal linkage by default, so you need
something like:

```
extern int const i = 42;
```

if you want to use it to instantiate a `template<int const*>`.

Comment: Holy Goat!! never knew this. SO \m/

Comment: +1: Summed it up far more concisely than I could! With some tasty extra tidbits to boot.

Comment: @Nasgul: Pick up a copy of Josutils Template book.If I remember correctly.Covered in chapter 5, which is introduction to Templates.James: +1 Nicely correlated.

Comment: In C, a global `const` by default has external linkage; in C++ it does not and must be initialized, unless explicitly declared `extern` (§5.4). - _CPP STROUSTRUP_

Comment: Very nice example and good definition. But, where is the allocation? Are we still referring to the same static main_stat in main.cpp ? Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner it depends on language[`C++`]'s implementation and Operating System its running on. its usually allocated in data segment[heap] dedicated to the process.

Comment: @CppLearner By "Where is the allocation?" do you mean "Which statement causes the memory to be allocated?" or "Where in memory is the variable allocated?"  For the first, if a statement is a definition, it causes memory for the variable to be allocated.  If you want to know where in the physical memory the variable will be placed, that's up to the implementation, but it will be somewhere with sufficient lifetime, so not on the stack.

Comment: @James Kanze Yes. Both, and for the latter, I hear a lot of "up to the implementation", but in general shouldn't static variables be allocated on the heap?

Comment: @CppLearner I've never heard of an implementation which allocates static variables on the heap.  Typically, there will be a "data" segment in the executable image; non-const static variables will be located in it, and const static variables in the text segment (if they are present at all).  Historically, non-const static variables would be located in something called the bss segment (on early Unix).  The only really key thing is that all static variables have an address which is fixed at link time; the address of auto variables is determined at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a declaration *and* definition:

```
int x;
```

Adding `extern` says "make it a declaration only, please".

But when you are providing a value, the line *has* to be a definition, so the variable gets `extern` storage class and you just happen to be defining it right in place anyway:

```
extern int x = 3;
```

The linkage semantics are as they usually are for `extern`, and the storage location is just as it would be for a normal definition `int x = 3` — i.e. in that TU at namespace scope. `myadd` is not relevant at all.

---

It's a hard one to "prove", because it's a case of "there's no rule against it".

Here's the best quote:

> `[n3290: 3.1/2]:` **A declaration is a definition unless it** declares
>   a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it
>   **contains the `extern` specifier** (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification25 (7.5) **and neither an initializer nor a
>   *function-body***, [..]

And some other pertinent information:

> `[n3290: 3.5/2]:` A name is said to have *linkage* when it might denote the same object, reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name introduced by a declaration in another scope:
>
> - **When a name has *external linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from scopes of other translation units or from other scopes of the same translation unit.**
> - When a name has *internal linkage*, the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes in the same translation unit.
> - When a name has no *linkage*, the entity it denotes cannot be referred to by names from other scopes.
>
> `[n3290: 3.5/12]:`The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope `extern` declaration
>   have linkage. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with
>   linkage having the same name and type, ignoring entities declared
>   outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, the block scope
>   declaration declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the
>   previous declaration. If there is more than one such matching entity,
>   the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found,
>   the block scope entity receives external linkage. [..]

Answer (score 2):

```
extern int main_stat=-3;
```

declares and defines `main_stat`, While:

```
extern int main_stat;
```

just declares the variable `main_stat`.

You can have as many declarations as you want but you can have only one Definition.

The keyword `extern`, indicates External Linkage. Without it `main_stat` would be static and have Internal linkage and you cannot not use `main_stat` from another translation unit.

> Is storage allocated in the stack frame of myadd ?

No definitely not on the stackframe of `add`.
Where the memory is allocated is implementation defined but you have the assurance that the object will be alive throughout the duration of the program.

Comment: I think that you may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Perhaps...In that case,What is the real Question?

Comment: I think, "how come `extern` can be used on a variable _definition_, and what happens then? Where is the storage? I thought `extern` always meant that storage is elsewhere"

Comment: While it is true that the purpose pf `extern` keyword is to give external linkage, the variable `main_stat` in the above example has external linkage by defualt. So, from the linkage point of view `extern` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @AndreyT: In C the `extern` is redundant but not in C++.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks. So extern with definition will create its own static global variable on the heap, rather than simply linking to the "elsewhere"?

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes, _I_ know that. Did you miss the faux quotation marks? (And, incidentally, my answer?) I'm trying to explain to Als what the question is.

Comment: @CppLearner: \*cringe\* "static" and "global" here are ambiguous terms to be avoided. "heap" is ... well, just don't get me started. And you used them all together >.<

Comment: @Als: I'm not saying it is completely redundant. I'm saying that it is redundant in this example with `main_stat`. And yes, it is redundant in this case in both C and C++. There's no difference in this respect between C and C++. The difference would arise if `main_stat` were `const`. But it isn't.

Comment: @AndreyT: Agreed. In this example(in absence of `const`) the extern is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The question apparently stems from some misconception.

Some people believe that `extern` keyword always turns a definition into a non-defining declaration. This is simply not true.

The keyword `extern` simply gives the declared entity *external linkage*. It can be applied to *declarations*. It can be applied to *definitions* (and remember that definitions are *declarations* as well).

So, saying that one can't define an `extern` entity is absolutely incorrect. One can. There's no problem with that at all.

The confusion is usually caused by the fact that when you apply `extern` to a definition like

```
int x; // no initializer
```

that definition suddenly turns into a non-defining declaration. This is true, but this is is no more than a one-off quirk of `extern` keyword that has to be remembered. If you take a definition like

```
int x = 42;
```

then applying the `extern` keyword to it will still preserve it as a definition, i.e. no quirks in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So let me collect my understanding here. Sorry if I am wrong again. So if we have int x declared in main.cpp, and then extern int x = 30, we would get linker error, because there is not memory allocation, right?

Comment: @CppLearner: Without the `static`, you would get the linker error because you have violated the One Definition Rule by supplying two definitions for the single variable `main_stat`.

Answer (score 1):

First, according to your comment, the file containing the main function has the definition `static int main_stat = 10;`. You should be aware that this is `not` the same variable as you defined in the file containing `myadd` because as static variable its scope is restricted to that file. Indeed, thanks to that static variable with the same name, `main` is not able to access the variable you defined in this file.

But that doesn't mean that either variable was created on the stack. Both are separate global variables, it's just that the variable `main_stat` in the file containing `main` (I'll call that file main file for short, and this one myadd file) is not available in any other file, while the variable `main_stat` you defined here can be accessed from any file which contains the declaration `extern main_stat;` (note: without initializer!). The main file cannot contain this declaration, however, because it would conflict with the static variable of the same name.

Note that giving an initializer makes your declaration of the variable a definition, that is, it's the same as if you had omitted the extern (note however that if a variable is declared constant, the extern may not be omitted because constants are by default static). The only global extern declarations which are not also definitions are those *with* extern, but *without* initializer.

Comment: celtschk Thank you. You answered almost everything I asked. But a few things confused me: (1) so we do have two separate main_stat at runtime, am I correct? (2) The unique main_stat in myadd function can be accessed by other files, right? (3) Finally, when extern is a declaration, we will use the definition elsewhere in the program, if I have another program calling myadd, and in that program I also have extern, I am still using main file's main_stat, am I right? 

Thank you.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Yes. (3) No. The `main_stat` from main is not accessible (by name) from any other translation unit under any circumstance. If other translation units declare `main_stat` with `extern` but none defines it as extern variable (either by omitting `extern` or by giving an initializer), the linker will complain that the variable doesn't exist. The static one in the main file is just not visible elsewhere.

Comment: @CppLearner: I forgot the "at-part", therefore this comment to notice you that I answered to your question in the above comment (the comment edit time for that other comment already has passed).

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else has covered this pretty well, but just to show the variants in one place:

```
int x;                    // #1
```

is a declaration and definition.  The initial value of `x` is zero.

```
int x = 3;                // #2
```

is a declaration and definition.

```
const int cx;             // #3
```

is illegal in C++.

```
const int cx = 3;         // #4
```

is a declaration and definition, but `cx` has internal linkage if this is its first declaration in the translation unit.

```
extern int x;             // #5
```

is a declaration but NOT a definition.  There must be a definition of `x` somewhere else in the program.

```
extern int x = 3;         // #6
```

is a declaration and a definition.  The `extern` is unnecessary, but makes things clear.

```
extern const int cx;      // #7
```

is a declaration but NOT a definition.  There must be a definition of `cx` somewhere else in the program.

```
extern const int cx = 3;  // #8
```

is a declaration and a definition.  The `extern` is needed unless the previous declaration above was already seen.

Comment: Thank you. How does it make things clear? I updated my post. Why do we want #6 to happen at all when #5 means definition of x exist elsewhere in the program? To keep things short, in the case of #6, I would have two different copies of stat variables named main_stat, one for main function, and one for myadd, am I correct?

Comment: I meant that though #6 means the same as #2, typing `extern` makes it more obvious that the variable will have external linkage.  The situation where two variables have the same name is a result of the `static` definition, not a result of the `extern` definition.

Comment: Thank you. But main's  static main_stat variable is not accessible by myadd if we didn't have extern. So how is "extern int x = 3" equivalent to  #2 ? If myadd has its own copy of main_stat, then the the keyword extern is pretty much ignored, right? Thanks.