# Initializer overrides extern

Tags: c++

I received a double definition error from the linker in a larger project I'm working on. I was surprised to see that I was allowed to accidentally include an initializer together with `extern`.

The following compiles, but I did not expect it to.

```
extern int var{3}; // declaration or definition?

//int var{3};

int main()
{
    int varb = var;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect `extern` to specify that a variable is only being declared, not defined, yet if I add an initializer, does it then become defined, why?

I have looked at the following questions, but they don't explain to me why this is allowed.

- [extern variables default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13660085/1460794)
- [Difference between declaration and definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411005/1460794)

The second answer does clarify the following:

> a declaration is a definition unless it contains the extern keyword
>   without an initializer or function body

So the specification does indicate that this should then be a definition, but why? Does that mean that the following two lines mean exactly the same thing?

```
extern int var{3};
int var{3};
```

Comment: Like it says, extern with an initializer is a declaration and a definition. It declares the var symbol as extern, and defines var as {3} in the same compilation unit.

Comment: @Rei So it has external linkage and then links to itself? Does that change anything?

Comment: external linkage means the symbol is undefined until linking stage. In this case, you define it in the same compilation unit, so it basically does nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8069831/560648